# V8 Embedded, Segmentation Fault after more run iteration

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, v8, embedded-v8

I am trying to use v8 in C++, I want to compile the js code in main thread and then I pass the `compiled_script` to the executor(child Thread). the `Run` execution process will run in threads.

Story: compile process is expensive and I need performance, therefore I will cache all compiled script at the beginning and will pass them to different threads for execution.

for testing this scenario I just create only one thread and passed the compiled script to it, after 1500 iteration in `for` loop, the program exited with Segmentation Fault Error.

The problem is related to thread, if I move the execution to outside the thread, it will successfully ended.

I investigate more but can not find any solutions.

***Complete Code :***

```
#include "include/libplatform/libplatform.h"
#include "include/v8.h"
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

bool ExecuteScript(v8::Isolate *isolate,
                   v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Script> compiled_script) {

  v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
  v8::TryCatch try_catch(isolate);
  v8::Local<v8::Context> context(isolate->GetCurrentContext());

  v8::Local<v8::Value> result;
  v8::Local<v8::Script> c = compiled_script.FromMaybe(v8::Local<v8::Script>());
  if (c.IsEmpty())
    std::cout << "Compile Script is Empty" << std::endl;
  if (context.IsEmpty())
    std::cout << "Conetxt is Empty" << std::endl;
  auto x = c->Run(context);
  if (!x.ToLocal(&result)) {
    v8::String::Utf8Value error(isolate, try_catch.Exception());
    std::cout << *error << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Script> CompileScript(v8::Isolate *isolate,
                                         v8::Local<v8::String> raw_source) {
  v8::ScriptCompiler::Source source(raw_source);
  auto unboundedScript =
      v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileUnboundScript(
          isolate, &source,
          v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileOptions::kNoCompileOptions)
          .ToLocalChecked();

  return unboundedScript->BindToCurrentContext();
}

int main() {
  v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  v8::Isolate *isolate;
  std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform;
  v8::Global<v8::Context> context_;

  v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(".");
  v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(".");
  platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  v8::V8::Initialize();

  create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
      v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);
  v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
  v8::HandleScope scope(isolate);

  v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);

  v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate, NULL, global);
  context_.Reset(isolate, context);

  {

    auto tt = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
      v8::Locker locker(isolate);
      v8::HandleScope thread_scope(isolate);
      v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);
      v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Script> compliedScript = CompileScript(
          isolate,
          v8::String::NewFromUtf8Literal(isolate, "var j=0; while(j<5) j++; "));
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        if (!ExecuteScript(isolate, compliedScript)) {
          std::cout << "Execution Error" << std::endl;
          return;
        }
      }
    });
    tt.wait();
  }

  v8::V8::Dispose();
  v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();
  delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
  std::cout << "Exit Normal" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this ?

Edit1:

1. Code Cleanup
2. valgrind memory leak result :

```
==2588106== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x2bf200000000, 0x2bf400000000) (noaccess)
==2588106== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x2bf200000000, 0x2bf400000000) (noaccess)
==2588106== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x2bf200000000, 0x2bf300000000) (noaccess)==2588106== Thread 9:
==2588106== Invalid read of size 8
==2588106==    at 0x2D7B24: v8::internal::Isolate::main_thread_local_heap() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x3F07EA: v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayIterator::BytecodeArrayIterator(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::BytecodeArray>, int) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0xD7EC2B: v8::internal::compiler::BytecodeGraphBuilder::BytecodeGraphBuilder(v8::internal::compiler::JSHeapBroker*, v8::internal::Zone*, v8::internal::compiler::NativeContextRef const&, v8::internal::compiler::SharedFunctionInfoRef const&, v8::internal::compiler::FeedbackCellRef const&, v8::internal::BytecodeOffset, v8::internal::compiler::JSGraph*, v8::internal::compiler::CallFrequency const&, v8::internal::compiler::SourcePositionTable*, int, v8::internal::CodeKind, v8::base::Flags<v8::internal::compiler::BytecodeGraphBuilderFlag, int>, v8::internal::TickCounter*, v8::internal::compiler::ObserveNodeInfo const&) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0xD92621: v8::internal::compiler::BuildGraphFromBytecode(v8::internal::compiler::JSHeapBroker*, v8::internal::Zone*, v8::internal::compiler::SharedFunctionInfoRef const&, v8::internal::compiler::FeedbackCellRef const&, v8::internal::BytecodeOffset, v8::internal::compiler::JSGraph*, v8::internal::compiler::CallFrequency const&, v8::internal::compiler::SourcePositionTable*, int, v8::internal::CodeKind, v8::base::Flags<v8::internal::compiler::BytecodeGraphBuilderFlag, int>, v8::internal::TickCounter*, v8::internal::compiler::ObserveNodeInfo const&) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x80E6FD: v8::internal::compiler::GraphBuilderPhase::Run(v8::internal::compiler::PipelineData*, v8::internal::Zone*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x7FFE81: void v8::internal::compiler::PipelineImpl::Run<v8::internal::compiler::GraphBuilderPhase>() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x7FC747: v8::internal::compiler::PipelineImpl::CreateGraph() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x7FC10F: v8::internal::compiler::PipelineCompilationJob::PrepareJobImpl(v8::internal::Isolate*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x253924: v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationJob::PrepareJob(v8::internal::Isolate*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x25F4E5: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::GetOptimizedCodeLater(std::unique_ptr<v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationJob, std::default_delete<v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationJob> >, v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationInfo*, v8::internal::CodeKind, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x25862D: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::GetOptimizedCode(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::ConcurrencyMode, v8::internal::CodeKind, v8::internal::BytecodeOffset, v8::internal::JavaScriptFrame*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x259905: v8::internal::Compiler::CompileOptimized(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::ConcurrencyMode, v8::internal::CodeKind) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==  Address 0xc1f8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==2588106==
==2588106==
==2588106==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xC1F8
==2588106==    at 0x2D7B24: v8::internal::Isolate::main_thread_local_heap() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x3F07EA: v8::internal::interpreter::BytecodeArrayIterator::BytecodeArrayIterator(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::BytecodeArray>, int) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0xD7EC2B: v8::internal::compiler::BytecodeGraphBuilder::BytecodeGraphBuilder(v8::internal::compiler::JSHeapBroker*, v8::internal::Zone*, v8::internal::compiler::NativeContextRef const&, v8::internal::compiler::SharedFunctionInfoRef const&, v8::internal::compiler::FeedbackCellRef const&, v8::internal::BytecodeOffset, v8::internal::compiler::JSGraph*, v8::internal::compiler::CallFrequency const&, v8::internal::compiler::SourcePositionTable*, int, v8::internal::CodeKind, v8::base::Flags<v8::internal::compiler::BytecodeGraphBuilderFlag, int>, v8::internal::TickCounter*, v8::internal::compiler::ObserveNodeInfo const&) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0xD92621: v8::internal::compiler::BuildGraphFromBytecode(v8::internal::compiler::JSHeapBroker*, v8::internal::Zone*, v8::internal::compiler::SharedFunctionInfoRef const&, v8::internal::compiler::FeedbackCellRef const&, v8::internal::BytecodeOffset, v8::internal::compiler::JSGraph*, v8::internal::compiler::CallFrequency const&, v8::internal::compiler::SourcePositionTable*, int, v8::internal::CodeKind, v8::base::Flags<v8::internal::compiler::BytecodeGraphBuilderFlag, int>, v8::internal::TickCounter*, v8::internal::compiler::ObserveNodeInfo const&) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x80E6FD: v8::internal::compiler::GraphBuilderPhase::Run(v8::internal::compiler::PipelineData*, v8::internal::Zone*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x7FFE81: void v8::internal::compiler::PipelineImpl::Run<v8::internal::compiler::GraphBuilderPhase>() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x7FC747: v8::internal::compiler::PipelineImpl::CreateGraph() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x7FC10F: v8::internal::compiler::PipelineCompilationJob::PrepareJobImpl(v8::internal::Isolate*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x253924: v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationJob::PrepareJob(v8::internal::Isolate*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x25F4E5: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::GetOptimizedCodeLater(std::unique_ptr<v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationJob, std::default_delete<v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationJob> >, v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationInfo*, v8::internal::CodeKind, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x25862D: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::GetOptimizedCode(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::ConcurrencyMode, v8::internal::CodeKind, v8::internal::BytecodeOffset, v8::internal::JavaScriptFrame*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x259905: v8::internal::Compiler::CompileOptimized(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::ConcurrencyMode, v8::internal::CodeKind) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==2588106==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==2588106==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==2588106==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==2588106==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==2588106==
==2588106== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2588106==     in use at exit: 541,595 bytes in 1,411 blocks
==2588106==   total heap usage: 2,072 allocs, 661 frees, 1,155,883 bytes allocated
==2588106==
==2588106== Thread 1:
==2588106== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1,252
==2588106==    at 0x483CFE3: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==2588106==    by 0x330BFC: v8::internal::Heap::SetUpSpaces() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x2D60B7: v8::internal::Isolate::Init(v8::internal::SnapshotData*, v8::internal::SnapshotData*, bool) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x2D6C88: v8::internal::Isolate::InitWithSnapshot(v8::internal::SnapshotData*, v8::internal::SnapshotData*, bool) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x5F789D: v8::internal::Snapshot::Initialize(v8::internal::Isolate*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x245612: v8::Isolate::Initialize(v8::Isolate*, v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x24581C: v8::Isolate::New(v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x2074BB: main (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==
==2588106== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 1,252
==2588106==    at 0x483CFE3: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:417)
==2588106==    by 0x330F6A: v8::internal::Heap::SetUpSpaces() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x2D60B7: v8::internal::Isolate::Init(v8::internal::SnapshotData*, v8::internal::SnapshotData*, bool) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x2D6C88: v8::internal::Isolate::InitWithSnapshot(v8::internal::SnapshotData*, v8::internal::SnapshotData*, bool) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x5F789D: v8::internal::Snapshot::Initialize(v8::internal::Isolate*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x245612: v8::Isolate::Initialize(v8::Isolate*, v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x24581C: v8::Isolate::New(v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x2074BB: main (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==
==2588106== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 1,252
==2588106==    at 0x483EA5D: operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&) (vg_replace_malloc.c:658)
==2588106==    by 0x53082E: v8::internal::String::ToCString(v8::internal::AllowNullsFlag, v8::internal::RobustnessFlag, int, int, int*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x530C0A: v8::internal::String::ToCString(v8::internal::AllowNullsFlag, v8::internal::RobustnessFlag, int*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x51AE2F: v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo::DebugNameCStr() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x27839C: v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationInfo::GetDebugName() const (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x7FB419: v8::internal::compiler::PipelineData::PipelineData(v8::internal::compiler::ZoneStats*, v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::OptimizedCompilationInfo*, v8::internal::compiler::PipelineStatistics*, bool) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x7FB1FF: v8::internal::compiler::PipelineCompilationJob::PipelineCompilationJob(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::BytecodeOffset, v8::internal::JavaScriptFrame*, v8::internal::CodeKind) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x807EDA: v8::internal::compiler::Pipeline::NewCompilationJob(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::CodeKind, bool, v8::internal::BytecodeOffset, v8::internal::JavaScriptFrame*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x2585F8: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::GetOptimizedCode(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::ConcurrencyMode, v8::internal::CodeKind, v8::internal::BytecodeOffset, v8::internal::JavaScriptFrame*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x259905: v8::internal::Compiler::CompileOptimized(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::ConcurrencyMode, v8::internal::CodeKind) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0xB2C785: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::CompileOptimized(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::ConcurrencyMode) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0xB28ACB: v8::internal::Runtime_CompileOptimized_Concurrent(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==
==2588106== 2 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 1,252
==2588106==    at 0x483EA5D: operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&) (vg_replace_malloc.c:658)
==2588106==    by 0x261383: v8::internal::CallDescriptors::InitializeOncePerProcess() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x3F0386: v8::internal::V8::InitializeOncePerProcessImpl() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x9ED455: v8::base::CallOnceImpl(std::atomic<unsigned char>*, std::function<void ()>) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x3EFFFD: v8::internal::V8::Initialize() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x23634A: v8::V8::Initialize(int) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x2074A2: main (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==
==2588106== 2 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 5 of 1,252
==2588106==    at 0x483EA5D: operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&) (vg_replace_malloc.c:658)
==2588106==    by 0x2620B0: v8::internal::CallDescriptors::InitializeOncePerProcess() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x3F0386: v8::internal::V8::InitializeOncePerProcessImpl() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x9ED455: v8::base::CallOnceImpl(std::atomic<unsigned char>*, std::function<void ()>) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x3EFFFD: v8::internal::V8::Initialize() (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x23634A: v8::V8::Initialize(int) (in /home/linux/v8)
==2588106==    by 0x2074A2: main (in /home/linux/v8)
```

Edit 2:
Compiling command :

`g++ sample.cpp libv8_monolith.a -I/usr/local/include/v8/ -I/usr/local/include/v8/include/ -lpthread -o v8 -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS`

Comment: *I investigate more but can not find any solutions.* -- The first thing you should do is figure out *why* the segmentation fault is occurring, instead of moving code around and hoping something works.

Comment: Yap you are right, sorry,  I forget to put the my valgrind memory check output.

Comment: (1) Please post repro details: which V8 version (git hash), how did you compile (both V8 and your app). -- (2) Note that this approach won't scale to several threads anyways: the `v8::Locker` (which is required!) ensures that only one thread can use the `Isolate` at a time. -- (3) What makes you think that `CompileScript` is slow? I'd expect it to be very fast.

Comment: (1) - v8 version is 9.1.0.0, (2) - Yes, I know, but in this example I just create only one thread and used `v8::Locker`  (not necessary in this code block), see the `main()`, (3) - in my real case I have around 10 scripts and I got so many requests (thousands)  from one of my C++ Object that needs to `Run` those scripts, and want to revoke compiling time during the execution, it significantly improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in V8 9.1 version and it has been fixed by google.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What's the first version that includes the fix?